# why intellij generates main and test modules inside a new module

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

I want intellij not to create main and test modules inside a new module. Everytime it regenarates a main and test modules under a new module.

- MyModule

  - src/main/
  - src/test/

I dont want these two main and test modules , How can I do this? Because deleting it doesn't delete them intellij recreates again

If I delete modules and put my sources under src the error is `Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt`

Comment: Does your project have a `build.gradle` or `build.gradle.kt`? If so, you need to edit that to tell IDEA what folder layout you want. But out of curiosity: why *don't* you want test/main modules? That's a very standard setup. If you don't want to write any tests, simply leave it empty.

Comment: the issue is android studio generates main and test as folders, but intellij creates them as seperate modules.

Answer (score 2):

IDE creates two separate modules for **main** and **test** because these are **standard** [**Gradle source sets**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html). Each source set has its own classpath and build configuration, so IDE correctly extracts each source set into a separate module, so you are able to configure the classpath and other build configuration for them independently. See also related [IntelliJ IDEA documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#gradle_source_sets).